# Build error under Mono when moving AssemblyVersion attribute to a separate file

Tags: c#, mono, gmcs

I have a C# library project with a build task that writes the current SVN revision into a file named Version.cs. The resulting file contains just this single line:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion(0.0.0.1325)]
```

I've removed the pre-existing `AssemblyVersion` attribute from the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

When compiling using Mono, the gmcs compiler doesn't like this - it throws the following parse error:

```
'value' is invalid attribute target. All attributes in this attribute section will be ignored
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Surely AssemblyInfo.cs isn't some sort of "special" file - I'd rather not have to write the version attribute into that...

I haven't tried it under Windows/VS.NET yet (it needs to be able to compile on both platforms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crap, nevermind, I hadn't quoted the version string (should be `[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.1325")]`...